# Testing HttpServletResponse addCookie

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockachino

I have this method I want to test with JUnit and Mockachino.

```
public void removeCookie(HttpServletResponse response, String name) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, "");
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

But how?

Answer (score 1):

My preferred mocking framework is **Mockito**. But you can try this with **Mockachino**:

```
@Test
public void providedNameAndEmptyValueCookieSetToResponse() {
   String name = "name";
   HttpServletResponse responseMock = mock(HttpServletResponse.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

   removeCookie(responseMock, name);

   Cookie cookie = catchCookie(mock);
   assertEquals(name, cookie.getName());
   assertEquals("", cookie.getValue());
}

private Cookie catchCookie() {
   ArgumentCatcher<Cookie> catcher = ArgumentCatcher.create(new AnyMatcher(Cookie.class));
   verifyOnce().on(responseMock).addCookie(match(catcher));

  return catcher.getValue();
}

@Test
public void zeroMaxAgeCookieSetToResponse() {
   HttpServletResponse responseMock = mock(HttpServletResponse.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

   removeCookie(responseMock, "any");

   Cookie cookie = catchCookie(mock);
   assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), cookie.getMaxAge());
}
```

Comment: If I run the `response.addCookie(cookie);`, then how to see the cookies if I save successd?

Answer (score 1):

A late answer for posterity's sake. Here is a snippet I used to test the `addCookie` functionality using EasyMock and the awesomeness that is [Capture](http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/Capture.html):

```
Capture<Cookie> getCookie = new Capture<Cookie>();

//mocking
HttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
Model model = new ExtendedModelMap();
HttpServletResponse response = createNiceMock(HttpServletResponse.class);
MyController controller = createMock(MyController.class);


// expectation
response.addCookie( capture(getCookie) ); //Capture would look for a Cookie object being sent to the addCookie method and grab that for you

// invocation
replay(controller, response);
String result = controller.someAction(request, response, model);
verify(controller, response);

// assertions
Cookie cookie = getCookie.getValue();
assertEquals("myCookie", cookie.getName());
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Ancient topic I've landed on here. For what it's worth I've found the MockHttpServletRequest and MockHttpServletResponse classes from Spring to be VERY helpful for this sort of stuff.  They can be used even if your project is NOT a Spring project.  Only one dependency is needed:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.20</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I do stuff like this:

```
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

    methodThatTakesRequestOrResponse(request, response);

    // Validate state (cookies, attributes, etc.)
    String attribute = (String)request.getAttribute("expected attribute name");
    assertNotNull(attribute);
    String cookie = response.getCookie("expected cookie name").getValue();
    assertNotNull(cookie);
```